# How to build new array in underscore/lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js, lodash

I have the following JSON data, containing nested arrays

```
{
    "works": {
        "work": [
            {
                "id": "001",
                "filename": "image1.jpg",
                "urls": {   
                    "url": [
                        {
                            "_type": "small",
                            "__text": "small-image.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "_type": "medium",
                            "__text": "medium-image.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "_type": "large",
                            "__text": "large-image.jpg"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "details": {
                    "flash": "0",
                    "model": "CAMERA MODEL 1",                    
                    "make": "CAMERA MAKE 1",                   
                }
            },

            {
                "id": "001",
                "filename": "image1.jpg",
                "urls": {   
                    "url": [
                        {
                            "_type": "small",
                            "__text": "small-image.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "_type": "medium",
                            "__text": "medium-image.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "_type": "large",
                            "__text": "large-image.jpg"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "details": {
                    "flash": "0",
                    "model": "CAMERA MODEL 2",                    
                    "make": "CAMERA MAKE 2",                   
                }
            }                     
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to rewrite the array so it looks like this

```
[{
    "id": "001",
    "filename": "image1.jpg",
    "_type": "small",
    "url": "small-image.jpg",
    "model": "CAMERA MODEL 1",                    
    "make": "CAMERA MAKE 1"  
}, {
    "id": "002",
    "filename": "image2.jpg",
    "_type": "small",
    "url": "small-image.jpg",
    "model": "CAMERA MODEL 2",                    
    "make": "CAMERA MAKE 2"  
}]
```

I've been reading up about chaining in Lodash, but so far not having much luck implementing it. Here's what I've got so far:

```
var flattened = _.chain(data).pluck("works")
         .concat(_.flatten(_(data).pluck("work")))
         .reject(_.isUndefined)
         .value()
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Both members of the *work* array have `"id": "001"`, but the output has `"001"` and `"002"`, is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much you care about using pure chaining, but using a lodash map might work if all you care about is transforming the data from one format to the other.

```
_(source.works.work).map(function(item){
  var image = _(item.urls.url).find({'_type': 'small'});
  return {
    id: item.id,
    filename: item.filename,
    _type: image ? image._type : null,
    url: image ? image.__text : null,
    model: item.details.model,
    make: item.details.make
  };
}).value();
```

This will result in:

```
[ { id: '001',
    filename: 'image1.jpg',
    _type: 'small',
    url: 'small-image.jpg',
    model: 'CAMERA MODEL 1',
    make: 'CAMERA MAKE 1' },
  { id: '001',
    filename: 'image1.jpg',
    _type: 'small',
    url: 'small-image.jpg',
    model: 'CAMERA MODEL 2',
    make: 'CAMERA MAKE 2' } ]
```

Comment: why `reduce` instead of `map`?

Comment: Thanks very much datfinesoul - I tried to implement, but I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'work' of undefined`. If I console.log(data) though, the data is loaded. Thanks again.

Comment: Bryan is correct, map will be the better answer, I was too tired when I responded.  I've updated the code above.  Desmond, here is the JSBin link to the answer.  http://jsbin.com/qareqatiri/1/embed?js,console